# Using a single router for multiple updates vs separating each model's controller into files

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So my colleague at our agency just picked up Node.js and he thinks that conjoining every single request into a single function is better than having multiple files. Example:

```
app.post('api/v1/:model/create', (req, res, next) {
    let modelName = req.params['model'];

    SCHEMAS[modelName].create(req.body, (err, model) => {});
});
```

So all POST request goes into this one function where it stores the object into mongodb (through mongoose). Similar case for delete, put, and get.

What I usually do is:

`/models/website/page.js`

```
app.post('/api/v1/pages/', (req, res, next) => {/* Store object to database here */});
app.delete('/api/v1/pages/:pageId', (req, res, next) => {/* Delete object from database here */});
```

`/models/website/navigation.js`

```
app.post('/api/v1/navigation/', (req, res, next) => {/* Store object to database here */});
app.delete('/api/v1/navigation/:navigationId', (req, res, next) => {/* Deletes object from database here */});
```

And so on and so on, you get the idea. Also, each of the files, in my method, has get, post, put and delete controllers for that corresponding model.

Can you guys enlighten me on this practice? Which and why is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I go with your approach with a bit of a modification, I use separate files for each namespaced route, and in those files I put all the calls to all the routes. so ie.

*server.js*

```
app.use('/api/v1/navigation/', require(./api/path/to/file/navigationRoutes'));
```

*navigationRoutes.js*

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){/* get request to the root of the namespace route, api/v1/navigation */});
router.post('/:navigationId', function(req, res, next){/* post request to api/v1/navigation/:navigationId */});

module.exports = router;
```

So I take the advantage of having all route calls in separate files, so it's easy to do isolated route specific work, and expand routes.

Comment: I do use this approach, I left it out in my example to simplify. I even require a group of controllers for each url segment. So: `/api, require('apiRoutes')`,  then inside `apiRoutes`, `/v1, require('v1Routes')` and so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I work the way you do.
The reason for that is some models require some extra stuff to be done to them, before you can same them (validation, adding values w/e).
Part of this is also security.

e.g. Are you "POST"-ing a new user? Does he have a username(or email) and a password? If he's suggesting you should just plainly insert the users password in the database, you might want to fire him...........
But for other models to be caught in the same part, my CMS has a `themes` model / schema. If I let those updates be handled by the same function, I can't really implement `multer` the way it should, no zip files would be saved (or registering a new user would crash on not having a `theme` property for example) and there would be no checking if that version of that theme already exists or if it is an update for that same theme.

Some things you can fix with mongoose Schemas, setting field properties like `required: true` and `unique: true`, but not everything can be done that way.

It might for at the start, if you're lazy, but eventually, you'll need to split those into different URL's and different files / modules.

The routing part of my CMS folder structure:

[image]